# scrollTop jumps to element, how to slow down?

Tags: performance, animation, window, scrolltop

Ok, so I now have this:

```
$(function(toContact){
    $('#contact').click(function(){
        $(window).scrollTop($('footer').offset().top);
    });
});
```

But now the screen just jumps to the element(footer). How can I control the speed in this function? I want it to go slower and ease.

Answer (score 0):

When I want to have full control of my scroll, I use a jquery plug in: localScroll. Take a look at it, you might like.

Comment: Can I implement this in what I already have(and if so, how)? Or do I have to change everything to implement localScroll?